# Wick Rotation vs Sokhotski-Plemeli Method to compute internal loop of Feynman correlators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, regularization, wick-rotation

When computing loop integrals in QFT, one often encounters integrals of the form
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dp^4}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{-i}{p^2+m^2-i\epsilon},$$ where we are in Minkowski space with metric $(-,+,+,+)$. One can Wick rotate to Euclidean space via the change of variable $p_0 \rightarrow ip_{0} $, and the integral becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dp^4}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{p^2+m^2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int d\Omega_4 \int_0^{\Lambda}dp\frac{p^3}{p^2+m^2}= \frac{1}{8\pi^2} \frac{1}{2}\left(m^2\log\left(\frac{m^2}{m^2+\Lambda^2}\right)+\Lambda^2\right),$$
where we imposed a momentum cutoff $\Lambda$ to regulate UV divergence.

Alternatively, one can use the Sokhotski-Plemelj Formula to evaluate the integral. We first note that
$$\frac{1}{-p_0^2 + p_i^2  + m^2 -i\epsilon} = \mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{p_i^2  + m^2 - p_0^2} \right) + i\pi \delta(p_i^2  + m^2 - p_0^2).$$
Computing the $p_0$ integral first, the principle value will vanish since it is symmetric about $p_0$, and only the delta function term contributes. We have
$$\int \frac{d^3p_i}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{dp_0}{2\pi} \pi \delta(p^2_i + m^2 - p_0^2) \\= \int \frac{d^3p_i}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{dp_0}{2} \frac{\delta \left(p_0-\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}\right) + \delta\left(p_0+\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}\right)}{|2p_0|_{p_0=\pm\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}}} \\= \int \frac{d^3p_i}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}} \\ = \frac{1}{2(2\pi)^3}\int d\Omega_3 \int_0^\Lambda dp\frac{p^2}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}} \\= \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda \sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2} + m^2 \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2} - \Lambda}{m} \right) \right), $$
which disagrees with the result calculated from Wick rotation.

I should expect both methods to produce the same result. Can anyone see why they disagree?

Comment: Also, in the second line it seems that there is a typo: the factor in front of log should be $m^2$ instead of $\Lambda^2$

Comment: related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192643/

Comment: No, you still have the typo. In the first method you should have $\Lambda^2+m^2\ln(m^2/(m^2+\Lambda^2))$. Note that here everywhere $\Lambda\gg m$, so both answers are identical in this sense.

Comment: @Diego If I also impose $\Lambda$ cutoff to the $dp_0$ integral, it wont't change the $dp_0$ integral result since $\Lambda > \sqrt{p_i^2 + m^2}$ and the integral over the delta function will give the same result.

Answer (score 5):

For the Wick rotation method I find
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda^2+m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\right),$$
because for me there is no reason to preserve $m^2+\Lambda^2$ in the denominator due to $\Lambda\gg m$.
For the second integral I find
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda\sqrt{\Lambda^2+m^2}-m^2\text{arctanh}\,\left\{\frac{\Lambda}{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2}}\right\}\right).$$
In this expression I know that $m\ll\Lambda$, so
$$\Lambda\sqrt{\Lambda^2+m^2}=\Lambda^2.$$
But for $\text{arctanh}$ I will be more gently. I know the following relation,
$$\text{arctanh}\,z=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+z)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-z)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1-z}{1+z}.$$
Next,
$$1-\frac{\Lambda}{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\Lambda^2+m^2}-\Lambda}{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2}}\approx \frac{m^2}{2\Lambda^2},$$
$$1+\frac{\Lambda}{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2}}\approx 2,$$
therefore
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda\sqrt{\Lambda^2+m^2}-m^2\text{arctanh}\,\left\{\frac{\Lambda}{\sqrt{m^2+\Lambda^2}}\right\}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\Lambda^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}.$$
Now I collect "angular" terms. For the Wick rotation method, I write
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\cdot(2\pi^2)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda^2+m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\right)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\Lambda^2+m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\right).$$
For the S-P method, I find
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\cdot(4\pi)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\Lambda^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\right)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\cdot\left(\Lambda^2+m^2\ln\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\right),$$
where I do not distinguish $2\Lambda^2$ and $\Lambda^2$. Both answers are similar in sense of $\Lambda\gg m$ behavior, but the second is two times smaller. It seems that it happens due to taking into account both zeros in the delta-function when the author performs integation over $p_0$. It seems that in oder to have causality, we have to deal with time-like vectors, which implies $p_0>0$ and we should take into account only positive zero of delta-function, $+\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}$, which adds the factor $1/2$ into the final answer. This situation realizes when one computes vacuum polarization diagram.

Comment: Thanks! For the comment regarding regularizations, if I also impose $\Lambda$ cutoff to the $dp_0$ integral, it wont't change the $dp_0$ integral result since $\Lambda > \sqrt{p_i^2 + m^2}$ and the integral over the delta function will give the same result. In that sense, the regularizations should be the same in both cases?

Comment: @Mr.Chen , I feel that something happens when you take both zeros of delta-function into account. For instance, when one computes vacuum polarization diagram by Sokh-Plem formula, it happens that the integration domain corresponds to time-like 4-vectors $p^{\mu}$, which implies $p_0>0$ and you have take into accoun only positive  zero, $+\sqrt{p_i^2+m^2}$. It gives additional $1/2$ factor into the final answer

Comment: Interesting. Can you please explain more about some intuition behind using only one zero? Mathematically, we should include both, right?

Comment: @Mr.Chen , you can check Landau-Lifshitz vol. 4, chapter XII, paragraph 115. No, we take only one zero in case of vacuum polarization.

Comment: @Mr.Chen , also check the point about the integration domains in the comment to answer for https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192643/

Comment: For your S-P result, it should be $2\Lambda^2$. It is only the $m^2 log$ term that is off by a factor of $1/2$, not the $\Lambda^2$ term. Also, the argument about causality that leads to restricting integral only to $p_0>0$ comes from physics motivation, but I'm more interested in computing the integral from two different methods. Mathematically speaking, why do I have to restrict integration to $p_0>0$?

Comment: @Mr.Chen , there is no difference between $2\Lambda^2$ and $\Lambda^2$ because $\Lambda$ is large. We implement regularizations in order to control divergent parts of integrals and provide *physical meaning* of our computations. From this point of view, we always should think about physics, not about math. For math point of view, my best understanding coincides with the point presented in the question metioned by Diego